# Simple WebRTC Remote Videos are not added sometimes

Tags: video, webrtc, simplewebrtc, openwebrtc, xirsys

We are integrating SimpleWebRTC for allowing the users to have group communication. Xirsys service is used for STUN/TURN servers. We followed the tutorial in the below link,

It uses the simplewebrtc sandbox singalling servers for testing purpose. It is working fine sometimes, but when a new users joins the room the peer objects are displayed in the UI but the remote video of those users are not added. When the user refresh the page then the video is displayed to him but for the other user who joined already is not able to view the other person's video. 
I guess the remote video stream added event is not received to the client. I even logged the messages and could not see the add remote stream message to the clients when new person joins the room. Even in the peer object the stream value is "undefined". 
I struck on this problem for couple of days. Kindly help me to identify the problem.

Below is the code for your reference,

```
       webrtc = new SimpleWebRTC({
       // we don't do video
       localVideoEl: (videoEnabled == 1)?"localVideo":"",
       remoteVideosEl: (videoEnabled == 1)?"remoteVideo":"",
       debug:false,
       // dont ask for camera access
       autoRequestMedia: (videoEnabled == 1 || audioEnabled == 1)?true:false,
       autoRemoveVideos:true,
       nick: name,
       media: { audio: (audioEnabled == 1)?true:false, video:(videoEnabled==1)?true:false},
       peerConnectionConfig:peerConnectionConfig
   });
```

PeerConnectionConfig - This value is retrieved from Xirsys API call.

Comment: I got it working! joinRoom() method should be called inside the readyToCall callback.

Comment: I am planning to run the signalmaster locally but i am getting CRON cross domain error if i change the URL to my signalmaster local ip. What should i do to overcome this?